# Windows Forms: How to display multiple values in a column

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a situation where in I have to display data in tabular form with each cell having multiple pair of values,list of values as show below

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
1           v1  v2    vl1
                      vl2
                      vl3
2           v3  v4    vl4
                      vl5
                      vl6
```

How can I do this using windows forms.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
JeeZ

Comment: Which control are you looking to use to display this?

Comment: I am planning to use data grid to display the values

Comment: just curious : is there a "hierarchical" relationship here : if so, have you considered a treeview.

Comment: no Bill, there is no hierarchical relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the wrapmode for the column to allow for '\n'?  Here's a quick example that seems to yield the format you posted above.

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column2", "Column2");            
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column3", "Column3");

//this is the key line...to allow \n in column
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "v1  v2", "vl1\nvl2\nvl3" });
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "v3  v4", "vl4\nvl5\nvl6" });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `DataGridView`, a solution would be to format those values into a single string, and display that string in the appropriate column of the grid.

A way of doing this would be to handle the `CellFormatting` event of the grid, and for that column put the formatted value into the `e.Value` property of the event arguments.

```
'if the grid is bound to a DataSet, we have a DataRowView as the DataBoundItem
var row = this.logicalGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;

if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) 
{
        e.Value = String.Format("{0}  {1}", row["Column1"], row["Column2"]);
        e.FormattingApplied = true; 
}
```

(An other solution would be to create a custom column type for the grid, and paint the cells yourself. Of course, this would be more complicated to do.)

Comment: thanks treaschf but how can i display list of values ie., Column3 values as show in the table above ?

Comment: You can put those into a string as well, possibly separated by new-line characters. However if you would like to have them in separate cells, you must have a new row for each one of them in the grid. For these rows you might leave the first cells (Column1, Column2) empty. There is no such thing in the DataGridView as the "rowspan" or "colspan" in HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an indication that you'd be better off using third-party controls.

The System.Windows.Forms controls are extremely limited.  I don't know whether this particular problem is solvable with the DataGridView, but if you have an application of reasonable complexity (say, 15 to 20 screens), you will probably save quite a bit of time and effort purchasing third-party controls.

I can highly recommend [Developer Express](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/) from personal experience: their controls have very extensive functionality, are reasonably prices, and their support people know the product up and down.

Answer (score 0):

A ListView Control would work as well.

```
    listView1.Items.Clear();

    listView1.View = View.Details;

    ColumnHeader ch1 = listView1.Columns.Add("Index");
    ColumnHeader ch2 = listView1.Columns.Add("Column1");
    ColumnHeader ch3 = listView1.Columns.Add("Column2");
    ColumnHeader ch4 = listView1.Columns.Add("Column3");

    ListViewItem lvi1 = listView1.Items.Add("1");    
    lvi1.SubItems.Add("1");
    lvi1.SubItems.Add("v1    v2");
    lvi1.SubItems.Add("vl1");
    ListViewItem lvi2 = listView1.Items.Add("2");
    lvi2.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi2.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi2.SubItems.Add("vl2");
    ListViewItem lvi3 = listView1.Items.Add("3");
    lvi3.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi3.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi3.SubItems.Add("vl3");
    ListViewItem lvi4 = listView1.Items.Add("4");
    lvi4.SubItems.Add("2");
    lvi4.SubItems.Add("v3    v4");
    lvi4.SubItems.Add("vl4");
    ListViewItem lvi5 = listView1.Items.Add("5");
    lvi5.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi5.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi5.SubItems.Add("vl5");
    ListViewItem lvi6 = listView1.Items.Add("6");
    lvi6.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi6.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi6.SubItems.Add("vl6");
```